# Proving a subset of sequences is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $p$ be a positive integer, and consider the set of sequences $(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ satisfying $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |x_i|^p < \infty$. Prove that this set is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$.

I am struggling to prove this. I know that I need to show that it contains the identity and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Since addition is taken component-wise, the zero sequences satisfy this since $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |0|^p = 0$, which is finite.

For scalar multiplication, if $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |x_i|^p < \infty$, then for scalar $\alpha$,
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |\alpha x_i|^p = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |\alpha|^p |x_i|^p = |\alpha|^p \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |x_i|^p < \infty. 
$$
I'm stuck on proving closure under addition. I'm trying to show that if $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |x_i|^p < \infty, \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |y_i|^p < \infty$, then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} |x_i + y_i|^p < \infty$. I want to use the triangle inequality in some way, but all I can say is that $|x_i + y_i| \leq |x_i| + |y_i|$ for a specific $i$. I can't "sum over $i$," because the sum on the left may not exist. Although, the sum on the right exists, so perhaps I can invoke the comparison test to say that the left-hand side converges, but that isn't guaranteed to hold after raising this to the power of $p$.

I'd appreciate any help with this problem, particularly on proving closure under addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fact that $f(x) = |x|^p$ is convex for $p \geq 1$.

Comment: I think in this context convexity means that for any $x_1, x_2$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the point $f(\alpha x_1 + (1 - \alpha)x_2) \leq \alpha f(x_1) + (1 - \alpha) f(x_2)$. So if I have that both sums on the right-hand side converge, the left-hand side converges by the comparison test. But I'm trying to figure out how this relates directly to this problem, since I can take $f(x) = |x_i|^p$ but I'd still have an $\alpha$ in the summand.

Comment: @Cardinality Take $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ in particular.

Comment: take $\alpha = 1/2$, we have $|x_1 + x_2|^p2^{-p} = |x_1/2 + x_2/2|^p  \leq |x_1|^p/2 + |x_2|^p/2 $. Scaling by constant factors has no impact on convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the map $x\mapsto x^p$ is increasing in $x$ for $x\geq 0$ and $p>0$, so for nonnegative $a,b$ you have $\max(a^p,b^p)=\max(a,b)^p$, and also if $a<b$, then $a^p<b^p$.

With these facts you can observe that for ***any*** $p>0$, you have

\begin{align*}
|x_i+y_i|^p & \leq (|x_i|+|y_i|)^p\leq (2\max(|x_i|,|y_i|))^p\\
&=2^p\max(|x_i|^p,|y_i|^p)\leq 2^p(|x_i|^p+|y_i|^p)\text{.}
\end{align*}

Then invoke the comparison test, as you suggested.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the second inequality. I can expand $(|x_i| + |y_i|)^p$ using the binomial theorem, but where does this bound come from?

Comment: @Cardinality   Don't expand anything, it comes from $(a+b)\leq 2\max(a,b)$, then raising to positive power is monotonic.